RCS not working on Rooted Pixel 8 even when RCS says "Connected" and SafetyNet passes Device Integrity and Basic Integrity
Context: I have a rooted pixel 8. It's running chiteroman's play integrity fix. I pass both Device and Basic Integrity when using both the Play Integrity API checker and YASNAC.
In Google Messages, RCS Chats say "connected". I'm on Mint Mobile.
Question: Any ideas why, when trying to text people I used to be able to text with RCS, I can no longer do so? The message just fails and disappears when I hit send

As you wrote you were able to use RCS before. What have you changed? The ROM, integrity fix, or the mobile network provider?

None of those things changed. The integrity fix was updated a few times, but I'm still passing so doubt that's the issue.
I'm worried Google implemented something on their side that's preventing it from working.

There seems to be a new version the play integrity fix that makes rcs work again (chiteroman's fix, v16.6)

@PrithviBoinpally if you are sure that's the fix, then feel free to post a proper answer :)

Google started blocking RCS messages on rooted phones or phones that have bootloader unlocked. See this article: Google Messages RCS is not working on rooted, custom ROM Android phones.
As stated in the article:

In recent weeks, Android users with rooted or bootloader unlocked phones have found that RCS in Google Messages does not work.
Specifically, users cannot send or receive RCS messages. According to one report, a phone number might pass verification, but Rich Communication Services functionality does not actually work. Another example shows messages disappearing after tapping the send button.

That's the reason you can't send RCS messages and why they disappear as soon as you send them. According to Google, they started blocking RCS meesages on rooted phones to prevent spam and abuse:

Google confirmed to us today that some of those phones are prevented from using RCS, and cited the need to prevent spam and abuse by making sure devices abide by the RCS standard’s “operating measures.”


Indeed. However, their method of blocking RCS on rooted phones is via the Play Integrity Check.
I confirmed yesterday with a friend on an iPhone that RCS works if using the Play Integrity Fix by Chiteroman (v16.6)
